# Draw a NetworkX graph as close as possible to single line diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a NetworkX graph `G`.

```
G.nodes  

NodeView((0, 1, 18, 24, 29, 2, 22, 3, 19, 5, 25, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21, 23, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32))

G.edges  
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 18), (1, 24), (1, 29), (18, 19), (24, 23), (29, 28), (29, 30), (2, 22), (22, 23), (3, 19), (19, 20), (5, 25), (25, 26), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (8, 20), (9, 10), (20, 21), (10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 15), (15, 16), (16, 17), (26, 27), (27, 28), (30, 31), (31, 32)])
```

How can I present the graph in somewhat similar to the representation below? I want something even remotely close to the structure below.
[image]

Comment: What aspect of the figure would you like to replicate exactly? Just the relative placement of the nodes to each other (i.e. the graph layout), or also the node markers and node labels?

Comment: Graph layout is the primary requirement. Node markers are not required. Node lables with ```with_labels``` argument should work.